# R Help Convert Date Time

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Hi I have the following columns in df and want to convert both to the same type of date formats. This is so that I'll be able to create a new col Duration where it takes 'End.Date.Time' - 'Start.Date.Time':

```
End.Date.Time    Start.Date.Time
1/5/2018 12:14   20171125 
1/5/2018 12:14   20171125 
1/5/2018 12:14   20171125 
30/5/2017 22:47  20170502
30/5/2017 22:47  20170502
30/5/2017 22:47  20170502
```

I tried

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(End.Date.Time = ymd_hms(End.Date.Time), Start.Date.Time = ymd_hms(Start.Date.Time))

out: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

The 'Start.Date.Time' values all  become NA. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The Base R way would be

```
transform(df, 
   End.Date.Time  = as.POSIXct(End.Date.Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), 
   Start.Date.Time = as.POSIXct(as.character(Start.Date.Time), format = "%Y%m%d"))

#        End.Date.Time Start.Date.Time
#1 2018-05-01 12:14:00      2017-11-25
#2 2018-05-01 12:14:00      2017-11-25
#3 2018-05-01 12:14:00      2017-11-25
#4 2017-05-30 22:47:00      2017-05-02
#5 2017-05-30 22:47:00      2017-05-02
#6 2017-05-30 22:47:00      2017-05-02
```

Or if you want both the columns as Dates you could do

```
transform(df, 
  End.Date.Time  = as.Date(as.POSIXct(End.Date.Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")), 
  Start.Date.Time = as.Date(as.character(Start.Date.Time), format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

---

With `lubridate`, we can use functions `dmy_hm` and `ymd` for conversion

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
   mutate(End.Date.Time = dmy_hm(End.Date.Time), 
          Start.Date.Time = as.POSIXct(ymd(Start.Date.Time)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(End.Date.Time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("1/5/2018 12:14", "30/5/2017 22:47"), class = "factor"), 
Start.Date.Time = c(20171125L, 20171125L, 20171125L, 20170502L, 
20170502L, 20170502L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: You could also `Map` each of the columns to output formats - `dat[] <- Map(as.POSIXct, dat, format=c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%Y%m%d"))`

Comment: I get NA values for the End.Date.Time when I try your suggestion.

Comment: @spidermarn It works fine at my end using the data in my post. Can you update your post with `dput` of your data? `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df))` if it is too long?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with lubridate, the below code should help.

```
df = structure(list(End.Date.Time = c("1/5/2018 12:14", "1/5/2018 12:14", 
                                  "1/5/2018 12:14", "30/5/2017 22:47", 
                                  "30/5/2017 22:47", "30/5/2017 22:47"), 
                Start.Date.Time = c(20171125L, 20171125L, 20171125L, 20170502L, 
                                    20170502L, 20170502L)), 
                .Names = c("End.Date.Time", "Start.Date.Time"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


df %>% 
  mutate(End.Date.Time = dmy_hm(End.Date.Time) %>% date, #dmy_hm outputs datetime. 
         Start.Date.Time = ymd(Start.Date.Time))
```

and as.Date with base also should work.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(End.Date.Time = dmy_hm(End.Date.Time) %>% as.Date, 
         Start.Date.Time = ymd(Start.Date.Time))
```

Comment: I get NA values for the End.Date.Time when I try your suggestion.

Comment: Checked again and its working. So not sure why. `date` having collision with other packages? Can you try `%>% lubridate::date()`

Comment: You can also try with as.Date from base system. `df %>% 
  mutate(End.Date.Time = as.Date(dmy_hm(End.Date.Time)) %>% as.Date, 
         Start.Date.Time = ymd(Start.Date.Time))`

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks so much for your solutions. I did the following and got what I needed:

```
df$Duration <- as.Date((ymd_hms(df$End.Date.Time))) - (ymd(df$Start.Date.Time))
```